# Cloud Run invoking Google Cloud Client Libraries without explicit Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-sdk

I have a Java Spring Boot Application deployed in GCP Cloud Run that tries to access Cloud KMS, However when the below code is executed it fails,

```
KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()
```

The error that occurs is,

```
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. 
They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. 
Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS 
must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials 
for more information. 
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134) 
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:125) 
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:97) 
    at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:70) 
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:168) 
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.create(GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.java:458) 
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.createStub(KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.java:668) 
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.<init>(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:191) 
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:173) 
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:164) 
    at ..................................................................................
```

In my understanding, as long as the Service Account using which the Cloud Run Service runs has the required role(s) to access the other GCP service(s), this scenario should work fine.

Why is that the `KeyManagementServiceClient` creation process  expecting an explicit `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing to the Service Account Key file here?

Please advise.

Comment: If you have that issue on Cloud Run (and not on your local environment) can you check if you use the latest version of the client libraries? Can you also share the Dockerfile of your container? (if you use Docker to build it)

Comment: Can you share the policies attached?

Comment: Does the spring service run with a service account allowed to call the key management services?

Comment: yes, from the local if I use the same service account for impersonation, I am able to access the KMS and perform decrypt and encrypt

Comment: We do not use Docker instead we use JIB (Java Image Builder) for building and pushing the image into the Artifact Registry

Comment: Below are the google cloud dependencies that we use,  


```dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.8.0')
  implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-kms'
  implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
  implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials'
  implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core'
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava'
}```

Comment: other settings include,
 --platform=managed --ingress=internal --vpc-egress=all-traffic

Comment: Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("<PROJECT ID>").build().getService();
            Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();

It resulted in the following error ```com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project. Permission 'storage.buckets.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).```

Answer (score 1):

After deploying the cloud run application using `gcloud run deploy`  with proxy settings like below `--set-env-vars "_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttps.proxyHost=<<https proxy>> -Dhttp.proxyHost=<<http proxy>> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<<https port>> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<<http port>>`, the exception is gone.

It appears like the `GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()` call makes an authentication call to Google APIs using the Cloud Run's service account and for this call to work, it needs the Internet Proxy as our GCP environment resides inside our VPN.